# Spark upgrade to 1.5.1 throws exception at run time

Tags: apache-spark

I upgraded to Spark 1.5.1 and experience problems when using RDD.map(). I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm.shaded.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm.shaded.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm.shaded.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:44)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getInnerClosureClasses(ClosureCleaner.scala:81)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2030)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:314)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:313)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:313)
at com.framedobjects.ClickInvestigation$.main(ClickInvestigation.scala:17)
at com.framedobjects.ClickInvestigation.main(ClickInvestigation.scala)
```

The error is thrown when mapping a RDD[String] to a RDD[CounterRecord]:

```
val counterRDD = counterTextRDD.map(mapToCounter(_))
```

My build.sbt looks like

```
name := "exploring-spark"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.1" withSources,
                        "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "2.6",
                        "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.4" % "test",
                        "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.8.2",
                        "org.yaml" % "snakeyaml" % "1.16",
                        "com.github.seratch" %% "awscala" % "0.3.+" withSources,
                        "org.apache.devicemap" % "devicemap-client" % "1.1.0",
                        "org.apache.devicemap" % "devicemap-data" % "1.0.3")
```

My feeling is there are some version mismatches (ASM?) but I can't pinpoint the problem. I compile against Java 1.8 and run 1.8.0_40. Any ideas?

Further investigation shows this to be a problem with Eclipse (Mars) and Scala-IDE. I can run the code in the spark-shell v1.5.0.

Comment: To clarify, which version of Spark were you upgrading from?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. From 1.4.0.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, changing the scala compiler target to jvm 1.7 fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the scala target version to 1.7 works. This is fixed as part of spark 1.6.0.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6152. They completely removed the asm dependency from external